# I'm unable to setup Pyramid and the deform_bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pycharm, pyramid, deform, fanstatic

I've just started working with Pyramid. I'm using PyCharm as an IDE and I've started with the "starter" scaffold. I'm trying to create some nice looking forms. I've installed deform and deform_bootstap. I've managed to get a form to display but it's not pretty like the examples of the widgets on the http://deformdemo.xo7.de/ajaxform/ site. I'm also am trying to make a tabbed form. I setup my code using this "how to" https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deform_bootstrap but the tabs don't seem to work. The documentation is sparse of this subject. What does the beginner need to know to get a twitter like form up and running? It seems that I'm missing all the wonderful CSS information in the .pt file and maybe that's the issue. Does Fanstatic provide a solution? How do I set all this up?

What's works best? I'm trying to stay away form HTML and CSS as much as possible but still have a clean looking site.

Comment: Deform is moving to bootstrap.  The deform_bootstrap package is obsolete.  The Kotti project has fanstatic packages that may help:  https://github.com/Kotti/js.deform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I now have a tabbed form.

1. Thanks to Sascha, I was able to use form.get_widget_resources() to make everything look pretty.
2. I was still unable to get the Tabs to display. The fix ended up being simple. I had deform_bootstrap_exta installed which ran on deform_bootstrap 0.2.8. I removed the deform_bootstrap_exta and updated to deform_bootstrap 0.2.9. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ToDoPyramid](https://github.com/indypy/todopyramid) - one of the [recommended pyramid sample applications](http://pyramid-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It uses deform & bootstrap to render a user account page. It is a nice application and serves well for learning purposes.

It currently depends on packages deform (0.9.4), pyramid_deform (0.2) and deform_bootstrap_extra (0.2.8). Current add-ons depend usually on deform<=1.999

You asked about CSS/JS setup for templates. You need to notice sample code like

```
form.get_widget_resources()
```

Depending on your Schema and widgets this call returns paths to JS/CSS that you need to inject into your templates. Background [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_deform/en/latest/#formview-usage) and [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/widget.html).

After all I am pretty happy with deform & bootstrap add-on packages. It not easy to start with, but afterwards is does a good job.

[Latest deform version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deform/2.0a2) has demo site and can be setup easily on your development system. Got it running as well. If you manage to work with TodoPyramid then you will notice the differences better. Documentation is currently a bit confusing and not very beginner-friendly. I am pretty sure this will be better, because documentation in pyramid ecosystem is usually very good.

I [refactored the TodoPyramid application](https://github.com/saschagottfried/todopyramid) to encapsulate code using SQLAlchemy (while learning it), make use of pyramid_deform FormView class, optimized deform JS/CSS injection and added tests. May be this will be of any help to you.

Comment: Thanks, I was just starting to use the TodoPyramid example.

Comment: Okay, I was able to peel apart the ToDoPyramid example and get my test from to show up with the pretty twitter like style. I still can't seem to get the tab view working. Any advice?

Comment: I remember trying the tab example. I did not work for me as well. I did not try to investigate or fix, since I use deform to stay away from widget HTML and CSS.